# Switching "outcome" and "exposure" in multiple logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

I read [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43319/exposure-and-outcome-can-be-switched-without-changing-the-odds-ratio) on whether switching the "outcome" and "exposure" changes the odds ratio in bivariate logistic regression. Which it does not. I'm wonder if this also holds for multiple logistic regression. For instance say we have

```
Y1 = alcohol abuse (0,1)
Y2 = cannabis abuse (0,1)
X1 ... X3 = demographic covariates
```

will

```
model 1: y1 ~ y2 + x1 + x2 + x3
```

and

```
model 2: y2 ~ y1 + x1 + x2 + x3
```

yield the same odds ratio for the relationship between y1 and y2? I tested this on a data set and model 1 and 2 did give different results. Is this because the covariates have different effects on y1 and y2?

Comment: If those are real data, what about trying a bivariate logistic regression, such as those in CRAN package VGAM? (function binom2.or) And, no, there is no reason your two odds ratos should be equal.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thank you! I asked the question because I've seen several articles were the association between two outcomes have been modeled like in my question. As if one of the outcomes were arbitrarily picked to be the IV. Bivariate logistic regression seems like a much better approach.